# How to use Tensorflow in local python project

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, google-colaboratory, tfx

I have a model created in Tensorflow that is already trained and accurate. How do I get this to run in a project? I can load the model but I can't figure out how to feed it a single image that my software is generating.

Also if this was a transfer learning project do I have to load and create a model before loading the weights?

All the tutorials are on how to set it up in the cloud or with a local server which I would like to avoid. I am tempted to save the data and then run it but that is a lot slower.

**Addition:**
My environment I am building this for is a google colab Jupyter notebook. The idea is to have no installation for users which is why it must be self contained.

Comment: You will have to take a look at both [Tensorflow Serving](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/guide/serving) and Docker.

Comment: I have been looking but why is this difficult to find info on? Is it not a normal thing to run a model for inferencing in a software program?

Comment: It's not hard, per se. It just requires knowledge of systems outside of python language. As an example, if you want to run inference in browser, you'll have to learn tensorflow.js.

Comment: @CharlesCurt, Please find the **`End To End Tutorial`**,https://colab.sandbox.google.com/github/tensorflow/tfx/blob/master/docs/tutorials/serving/rest_simple.ipynb, which demonstrates how to perform `Inference` of an `Image` on `Tensorflow Saved Model` using `Tensorflow Serving`, in the `Google Colab Environment`.